# List View doesn't render items in Details view

Tags: winforms, listview, c++-cli, detailsview

```
VariableBox = gcnew ListView();
VariableBox->Font = ScriptEditorOptions->FontSelection->Font;
VariableBox->Dock = DockStyle::Fill;
VariableBox->BorderStyle = BorderStyle::Fixed3D;
VariableBox->BackColor = ScriptEditorOptions->BCDialog->Color;
VariableBox->ForeColor = ScriptEditorOptions->FCDialog->Color;
VariableBox->DoubleClick += gcnew EventHandler(this, &ScriptEditor::VariableBox_DoubleClick);   
VariableBox->View = View::Details;
VariableBox->MultiSelect = false;
VariableBox->CheckBoxes = false;
VariableBox->FullRowSelect = true;
VariableBox->HideSelection = false;
VariableBox->Tag = (int)1;

ColumnHeader^ VariableBoxName = gcnew ColumnHeader();
VariableBoxName->Text = "Variable Name";
VariableBoxName->Width = 70;
ColumnHeader^ VariableBoxType = gcnew ColumnHeader();
VariableBoxType->Text = "Type";
VariableBoxType->Width = 50;
ColumnHeader^ VariableBoxIndex = gcnew ColumnHeader();
VariableBoxIndex->Text = "Index";
VariableBoxIndex->Width = 50;
VariableBox->Columns->Add(VariableBoxName);
VariableBox->Columns->Add(VariableBoxType);
VariableBox->Columns->Add(VariableBoxIndex);
VariableBox->ColumnClick += gcnew ColumnClickEventHandler(this, &ScriptEditor::VariableBox_ColumnClick);
```

I have the above code in a WinForms application. The control is added to the main form directly. For some reason, it never renders any items or columns when the layout is set to *Details* - Only the scroll bars are visible. The following code is used to add items to its collection:

```
ListViewItem^ Item = gcnew ListViewItem("Qw");
Item->SubItems->Add("Int");
Item->SubItems->Add("10");
VariableBox->Items->Add(Item);
```

Switching to any other view (at either run-time or design-time) fixes the issue. Any ideas on why this is happening ?

EDIT: Bump! Or is that not allowed ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that I was removing the column headers before the control was displayed.